# integrating between multiple persistence units (xa and non-xa) in javaee

Tags: jakarta-ee, persistence.xml

I have two persistence units in my persistence.xml, one XA and another non-xa (to increase performance when work is only releated to a single datasource and I dont need global transaction).

```
<persistence-unit name="pu-negin88" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/glDS</jta-data-source>
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/glDS</non-jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="pu-nonxa" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/bancononxaDS</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

I'm passing an object loaded by the XA persistence unit to a method in a stateless session bean which uses a non-xa persistence unit and requires a new transaction. In this session bean I use some properties of this object to load other objects from the DD and at this time, I'm getting the following exception:

```
javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation.
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1218)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:195)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:83)
        at $Proxy604.expireUserSession1(Unknown Source)
        at com.kishware.core.framework.controller.AuthenticationController.control(AuthenticationController.java:60)
        at com.kishware.core.framework.interceptors.TosanBusinessMethodInterceptor._intercept(TosanBusinessMethodInterceptor.java:339)
        at com.kishware.core.framework.interceptors.TosanBusinessMethodInterceptor.intercept(TosanBusinessMethodInterceptor.java:190)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:579)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:483)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:205)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:3978)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:189)
        at $Proxy395.deposit(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.InvokerImpl.invoke(InvokerImpl.java:81)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbInvokerImpl.invoke(EjbInvokerImpl.java:82)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:93)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:147)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.tx.service.TxServerPipe.process(TxServerPipe.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:218)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:129)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:444)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:113)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:87)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:155)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.AdHocContextValve.invoke(AdHocContextValve.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:571)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:571)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1080)
        at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:272)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:719)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:684)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:561)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:666)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1):

> (to increase performance when work is only releated to a single datasource and I dont need global transaction).

First of all, have you actually measured that this increases performance? As a general rule, when there's only 1 transactional resource participating in a transaction, the transaction provider optimizes automatically.

As of the actual exception, perhaps you should show the code that you're actually using. I wonder if the transaction used for loading the entity via the XA persistence unit has already ended.

If the transaction has ended, your entity will be detached and nobody will remember anymore where it originally came from. Since this other stateless session bean you speak of requires a new transaction, you have a form of nested transactions and that might be the problem if the properties of the entity are lazily loaded.

Normally an `AccessLocalException` is actually more indicative of a security issue, e.g. when both beans are in different security realms and/or have `@RolesAllowed` defined on them which the security principal (the caller) doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem and now I haven't this exception. It was because the object loaded by the first persistence unit was unmanaged in second persistence unit and when I wanted to use the object, this exception was thrown. I used getReference() method and create a hollow  object from the main object and did my work.